# How show Tooltip after click on point?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have code (jquery ui):

```
.arrow{
    background-color: red;
}

$(function () {
        $(document).tooltip({
            position: {
                my: "center top+20",
                at: "center"
            },
            content: function () {
                return $(this).prop('title');
            }
        });
    });




<div class="item-point" data-top="130" data-left="300"  id="point1">
<div><a href="#" class="toggle tooltips"title="sample text <b>yes!!</b>" data-placement="top"></div>
```

I would like the tooltip to display it after clicking on the point - not after hovering.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Html Code:

```
<div id="tt">Test</div>
```

JS code:

```
  var id = "#tt";
var $elem = $(id);

$elem.on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$elem.tooltip({ items: id, content: "Displaying on click"});

$elem.on("click", function (e) {

    $elem.tooltip("open");
});
```

Try this code,it will show your tooltip onclick and will stay there untill you click out.
here is the working code for you. [Onclick tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/c6wa4un8/57/)